# How to add text labels to marks with Google map API v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

One can add "marks" to a map created with Google Map API v3.  But such marks shows a red disk without any text label immediately visible.  Is there a way to show text labels immediately visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you could use is [infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox//docs/examples.html)

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map.html)